# Image as toolbar background?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I've added an actionbar to my android app and wanted to set an image as icon, centered on the actionbar. There are only tutorials to change the default icon, but I want the icon to stay there and add my image next to it. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

**My code if needed**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActionBar actionBar;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in toolbar of xml put image view and set it width and height to match parent.

Answer (score 0):

it is Simple, you can use Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/image.png"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar tool=findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tool);
     actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```